# Bonobo Git Server Windows Authentication Error

Tags: git, iis, windows-authentication, bonobo

I have recently installed Bonobo Git Server on my local IIS server. I've got windows authentication and the Active Directory membership service working correctly via the web ui (Authentication works, AD groups/teams/admins are imported as expected).

However, when trying to clone a repository I am presented with this error from the git client.

> fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://example.org/myrepo.git/'

I have tried using every variation of my username/domain combo, for instance:

`username
domain\username
domain\\username
domain\\\username
username@example.org
username@ad-server.example.org`

All produce the same response (though username@example.org seems to take longer to timeout).

I've turned windows authentication off and used bonobo's internal authentication/membership scheme and was able to clone the desired repo without a problem.

So, in short, Windows Authentication/AD member service works for http clients but not for my git client. Any ideas?